# Expression for a enjoyable moment being taken away before it could be celebrated

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example, being slapped with an unforeseen cost of selling an item making the money earned less enjoyable.

An expression for the unexpected cost raining on my parade, or for being too optimistic that I had overlooked those costs.

Comment: _Short-lived joy/success_ maybe.

Comment: "Raining on one's parade" is pretty good. Depending on the context, the somewhat sarcastic expression "snatching defeat from the jaws of victory" (which reverses the usual order of "defeat" and "victory") could work.

Comment: Ephemeral......

Answer (score -1):

Your enjoyable moment proved to be a **chimera**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chimera)
> a hope or dream that is very unlikely ever to come true

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chimera)
> A chimera is an unrealistic idea that you have about something or a hope that you have that is unlikely to be fulfilled

> [Merriam Webster](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chimera)
> an illusion or fabrication of the mind
> especially : an unrealizable dream

Comment: I do not find *chimera* in related questions and answers on this site, so I believe the question is not a duplicate, and should not be closed.

Comment: This isn't the right word for what the OP is looking for. A *chimera* doesn't exist in reality, but only in the mind, whereas what the question describes is a **real thing** the enjoyment of which is short-lived, i.e. *ephemeral*.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica To what real thing do you refer? The question is about enjoyment. Enjoyment is in the mind, just as is a chimera.

Comment: Quoting directly from the question – "For example, being slapped with an unforeseen cost of selling an item making the money earned less enjoyable." The "real thing" is (a) selling the item for profit, followed by (b) being "slapped" with unexpected costs. These events aren't in the mind. They're quite real. The pleasure is no chimera, it's quite real too – but it's *ephemeral*.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Clearly, our definitions of "real" are different. But nobody else seems to care so let's leave it at that.